# BASH: how would one execute rm on an array of file names?

Tags: bash

Forgive my noob-ness. I have a script that I want to use to remove all non English .lproj files.

```
if [ -f /var/mobile/Documents/Local\ Cookies/Clean ];    
then   
    echo "Last run: $(cat /var/mobile/Documents/Local\ Cookies/Clean) "    
else    
    echo "Hasn't been run yet "    
fi    
echo (grave)date(grave) > /var/mobile/Documents/Local\ Cookies/Clean   
sleep 1    
echo "Found files:"  
Lang=( $( find / -name "*.lproj" ! -name "en*" ! -name "En*" ! -name "Base*" ) )  
echo ${#Lang[@]}  
rm -r $Lang >/dev/null 2>&1  
echo "Finished cleaning language files."  
sleep 1  
echo "Found files:"  
iphone=($( find /  -name "*~iphone" ) )  
echo ${#iphone[@]}  
rm -r $iphone >/dev/null 2>&1  
echo "Finished cleaning iPhone files."
```

The only problem is that I (being a beginner)   have no idea how I might use the `rm -r $...`  parts to remove the files found on the $Lang   and $iphone arrays.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35079222/5678086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another suggestion is to use xargs command combined with find

```
Lang=( $( find / -name "*.lproj" ! -name "en*" ! -name "En*" ! -name "Base*" -type f | xargs rm -f) )
```

Btw you should use the variable `Lang` to check the operation result

```
if [ -z "${Lang}" ];then
    echo "all files removed"
fi
```

you should made some test to make it more efficient.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 test1.lproj                                                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 test3.lproj                                                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 test2.lproj                                                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 test4.lproj                                                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 test5.lproj                                                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 testEn7.lproj                                                                                                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 test6.lproj                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1 cg cg    0 Jan 29 03:16 testBas87.lproj                                                                                                          
-rwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg  229 Jan 29 03:16 test.sh  
> result
bash-4.3$ ./test.sh                                                                                                                                                                                       
start                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Lang[]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
all files removed                                                                                                                                                                                         
end                                                                                                                                                                                                       
bash-4.3$  
bash-4.3$ ls -ltr                                                                                                                                                                                         
total 12                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg  229 Jan 29 03:16 test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rm -r ${Lang[@]} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and

```
rm -r ${iphone[@]} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Edit://
I just tried it, you can also just use the normal variable name like $Lang, it should work too. Whats your problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: I'm getting a constant "48" and "2" im assuming ambiguous numbers of the files it's finding, but not deleting.

Comment: The values come from the echo ${#Lang[@]}, i dont know what you want to show with that command :D List the found files? -> remove the #. The current command shows the length of the string.

Also your find command is wrong. Remove the parentheses and change it to 
Lang=$( find / -name "*.lproj" ! -name "en*" ! -name "En*" ! -name "Base*" )

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, Replace

```
rm -r $Lang >/dev/null 2>&1 
rm -r $iphone >/dev/null 2>&1
```

with

```
rm -r En* *.lproj en* *~iphone  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I'm assuming just putting a "!" in front of a name would make it not remove those file names?